# Problem applying physics into MMD Model in Blender

Tags: bones, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody, mmd-tools

When I apply the physics on my MMD model, part of her bosom and her skirts go floating instead of hanging.
Any help?

Blend file:
[image]

Comment: Welcome! Please use this site to share blender files https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: There is too much total mass hanging from the topmost joints.  The rigid bodies are getting far enough away from each to break the joints.  Realize that with a model at this scale, gravity is acting at about 8 times the force as most MMD models.